# Getting "cannot locate symbol _Z17rsMatrixTranslateP12rs_matrix4x4fff" using the RenderScript Support Library?

Tags: android, renderscript

so my app is crashing mainly on any device running less than 4.4 and this is what the crash log is reporting to me:

```
android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptC.<init>(ScriptC.java:69)
at com.apporio.glitchr.ScriptC_translate.<init>(ScriptC_translate.java:41)
at com.apporio.glitchr.ImageEffects.fastTransform(ImageEffects.java:417)
at com.apporio.glitchr.ImageEffects.doNewVHS(ImageEffects.java:308)
at com.apporio.glitchr.EffectFactory.vhsEffect(EffectFactory.java:70)
at com.apporio.glitchr.EffectFactory.doEffect(EffectFactory.java:28)
at com.apporio.glitchr.EffectActivity$8.run(EffectActivity.java:303)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

The point in the Java it's crashing at is:

```
ScriptC_overlay e = new ScriptC_overlay(rs, context.getResources(),
            R.raw.overlay);
```

The rs file has this kernel:

```
void root(const uchar4 *v_in, uchar4 *v_out, const void *usrData, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

    rs_matrix4x4 matrix;
    rsMatrixLoadIdentity(&matrix);
    rsMatrixTranslate(&matrix, xAmt, yAmt, 0.0f); //CRASH?
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out what's wrong.  Any ideas, Stack Overflow?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had many missing symbols in the support library unfortunately. This bug (and other missing symbols) are all fixed in AOSP right now, but you will have to wait for an SDK update before making use of it.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  So, is there any sort of work around that I can do to fix the bug?  I hate that my app crashes on people's phones and hopefully I won't have to unpublish it until an SDK update comes out.

Comment: Can you write it without using rs_matrix? I know that skips some of the underlying optimizations (and makes you have to write/maintain more code), but you can probably just rip out the parts from our existing C implementation in AOSP to do it.

Comment: so I've rewritten my script to remove occurrences of the missing symbols by basically reimplementing them.  It seems to work on my Nexus devices running 4.1-4.4 but still crashes on some of my users' devices.  If I compile AOSP, is there a way to extract the support library and use it in my project?  If not, is there any way to build your team's fixes or are they not public facing yet?  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Do you have logs for the crashes? As far as rebuilding the latest support library in AOSP, it can be done. It just won't integrate with Eclipse, etc. easily (since I don't work on that part of things, and have never successfully built anything for Android other than with Makefiles). If you want to rebuild the support library, you can check out AOSP. There is an update_rs_prebuilts.sh script in frameworks/rs. You can run that to produce the appropriate .so files and compilers. At that point, you can possibly put them where Eclipse will see them.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help!  My crash reports say:

`android.support.v8.renderscript.r: Error loading RS jni library: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown failure
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.a(Unknown Source)
...
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)`

I'll try recompiling the support library today!