# rsSendToClient Fails with exception

Tags: java, android, renderscript

'rsSendToClient' Fails with following error:

> 02-15 04:50:23.102: E/RenderScript(5147): Unable to open shared library (/data/data/com.isssist.magnitab//lib/librs.mono.so): Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:  1420 cannot locate '_Z14rsSendToClienti'...
>   02-15 04:50:23.102: E/RenderScript(5147): Unable to open system shared library (/system/lib/librs.mono.so): (null)
>
> android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.

```java
 void filter() {  
   rsDebug("Number of rows:",rsAllocationGetDimX(gIn));
   for (int i = 0; i < rsAllocationGetDimX(gIn); i += 16)
    {
        const  int32_t *element = rsGetElementAt(gIn, i);
        //rsDebug("Number of rows:",sizeOf(gIn));

        //rsDebug("---------------:",(element[0]));




        int lumOne = (element[0]);
        lumOne += 128;
        pixelData[lumOne]=pixelData[lumOne]+1;

        // Bin Second Pixel Value
                    const int32_t *element2 = rsGetElementAt(gIn, i+2);
        int lumTwo = (element2[0]);
        lumTwo += 128;
        //pixelData[lumTwo]++;
        pixelData[lumTwo]=pixelData[lumTwo]+1;


    }

    rsSendToClient(1);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. [Getting "cannot locate symbol _Z17rsMatrixTranslateP12rs_matrix4x4fff" using the RenderScript Support Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001383/getting-cannot-locate-symbol-z17rsmatrixtranslatep12rs-matrix4x4fff-using-the) is where it was first reported. I have it fixed in AOSP, but the SDK has not been released with a fix just yet.

Comment: Is There any other way i can transfer this pixelData array to to my main program?

Comment: Use allocations. Do not use messages for transferring large arrays of data or anything like that. There are good examples of Allocation.copyFrom/copyTo on the web.

Comment: Your code above is not going to get executed in parallel because you are using a single-threaded invoke function ("filter" in this case). Look at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/levels-in-renderscript.html for a simple kernel example. Even if you are not using a Bitmap, you can use the same kinds of copyFrom/copyTo calls with your pixel input/output.

Comment: OK thank you. I am trying that but getting new error could have a look  at that as well..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796752/android-render-script-error-when-assigning-to-out-paramaeter