# Android Render Script Error when assigning to Out paramaeter

Tags: java, android, c, renderscript

i am getting error

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x51b71000 (code=1), thread 3696 (sssist.magnitab)
```

Whenever i assign value to out parameter  for send back the values main app , when i remove assignment error goes away , here is my code ,(below part the android code )

```
 void root(const char *in, int *out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {\
    int  pixelData[size];
    for (int i = 0; i <size ; i += 16)
        {
            //rsDebug("---------------:","3333");



            int lumOne = in[i];
            lumOne += 128;
            pixelData[lumOne]=pixelData[lumOne]+1;

            int lumTwo = in[i+2];
            lumTwo += 128;
            //pixelData[lumTwo]++;
            pixelData[lumTwo]=pixelData[lumTwo]+1;

        }

        out[10]=23;


}
RenderScript mRS;

       mRS = RenderScript.create(activity);
       ScriptC_mono mScript;
       // Convert to Bitmap

       Allocation alloc = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.I8(mRS), array.length, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
       alloc.copyFrom(array);
       int[] ret = new int[array.length];
       int[] ret2 = new int[array.length];
       Allocation alloc_out =    Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.I32(mRS), array.length, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
       alloc_out.copyFrom(ret2);

       mScript = new ScriptC_mono(mRS, activity.getResources(),R.raw.mono);
       mScript.set_size(array.length);
       mScript.forEach_root(alloc, alloc_out);
       alloc_out.copyTo(ret2);

       //byte [] outarray = array;
       // mOutPixelsAllocation.copyTo(outarray);
        mRS.finish();
```

help me to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only be writing to out[0], and never to out[10]. The out pointer is advanced automatically and root() is run on each cell in your input/output allocations. Each individual cell has this function called with a valid in/out pointer pair that really maps to in[y][x], out[y][x] (or 1D as appropriate).

Comment: Thank you very much for reply , error comes even i change it to  out[0]=in[0];     And is foreach function calling root for each cell in allocation? what need to do here is   read this large "array"     and create rather small array representing that. Since it is taking time i am trying to move this calculation to GPU so it will be faster.

Comment: You are also reading "in[i+2]" up above. You can't do that without faulting either.

Comment: Is there any way that i could pass a array and do the calcualtion in renders script and get the result back?

Comment: You should look at the ImageProcessing source files (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/java/tests/ImageProcessing/src/com/android/rs/image). Take a look at convolve3x3.rs to see how you can use rsGetElementAt_*() to access adjacent memory. There is also an rsSetElementAt_*() set of functions that work to write those adjacent cells (although you have to be careful to not produce conflicting writes between threads - same as any parallel language).